# eonasdan datetime picker second same value as first if empty

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ on a site to fil al scheduler. I use the next code to limit the range of the datepickpopups.

```
$("#startcalendardatepicker").on("change.dp",function (e) {
   $('#endcalendardatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setStartDate(e.date);
});
$("#endcalendardatepicker").on("change.dp",function (e) {
   $('#startcalendardatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setEndDate(e.date);
});
```

At the beginning both the fields are empty. Because most of the tasks in the scheduler are one day taksk I want to populate the second input field with the value that is entered in the first but only if the input is empty. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Test if the input is empty before populating it.

```
$("#startcalendardatepicker").on("change.dp",function (e) {
    if ($('#endcalendardatepicker').val() === '')
        $('#endcalendardatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setStartDate(e.date);
    }
});
```